# ListView with ComboBox as item template don't update source when selection in ComboBox changes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have `ListView` bound to `ObservableCollection<string>` and each item should be displayed as `ComboBox`. Problem is, when i change selection in `ComboBox`, it doesn't update `ObservableCollection<string>`. Here is xaml:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CellValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Column.CellValueChoices, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}" SelectedIndex="0" IsEditable="True">
                            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <behaviors:CellFocusBehavior/>
                                <behaviors:FocusOnLoadBehavior/>
                            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <ComboBox.InputBindings>
                                <KeyBinding Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ValidateAndInsertNewCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}" Key="Tab"/>
                            </ComboBox.InputBindings>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

`DataContext` for `ListView` is `CellViewModel` object that contains `ObservableCollection<string> CellValue`.

Comment: It might be helpful to include some more information as to what CellValueChoices is, and how that relates to the CellValue collection. I can't see anything in your XAML that *should* update the CellValue collection. The SelectedItem of the ComboBox doesn't appear to be bound to anything, so it's not clear how you're managing the updated values.

Comment: `CellValueChoices` is just onother `ObservableCollection<string>` property on `CellViewModel` and it populates `ComboBox`. I am not quite sure how to bind `SelectedItem`.

Comment: ObservableCollection only updates in case items are added or removed. There is no mechanism that listens for changes on the items. To provide something more helpful: Use Viewmodels with a string-type property as items for your OC, and implement NotifyPropertyChanged on these Viewmodels.

Comment: I don't need  `NotifyPropertyChanged` becouse i don't need `UI` updated. I need UI to update my source. Let's change `ComboBox` for a `TextBox` and forget about `ItemsSource` CellValueChoices` binding. So, i have `ListView` of `strings` but i render them as `TexBoxes`, my question is, how do i update that `string` when i type in `TextBox`.

Comment: try IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem on the listview. Also Tools/Options/Debugging/Outputwindow/Wpf/Databindings can be very helpful when trying to detect such issues

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your xaml, it seems to me that you think "ItemsSource="{Binding CellValue, Mode=TwoWay" is the way of binding a wpf control to it's corresponding VM property which is not quite right. The Itemsource binding should only be one way as the ViewModel loading the list that implement INotifyCollectionChanged to the GUI in one-way fashion. Making the ItemsSource binding to TwoWay doesn't make the GUI know how to update all the control's value inside the DataTemplate back to your ViewModel.

Instead, you should binding each control to each one of your ViewModel property in order to do that. I made you a sample for it.

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class OrderViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> ComboBoxOptions { get; set; }

    private string orderId;
    private string instrumentId;
    private string selectedComboOption;

    public OrderViewModel()
    {
        ComboBoxOptions = new ObservableCollection<string>
        {
            "Option1",
            "Option2",
            "Option3",
        };            
    }

    public string OrderId
    {
        get { return orderId; }
        set
        {
            orderId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string InstrumentId
    {
        get { return instrumentId; }
        set
        {
            instrumentId = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string SelectedComboOption
    {
        get { return selectedComboOption; }
        set
        {
            selectedComboOption = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

[Export]
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private OrderViewModel selectedOrder;
    public ObservableCollection<OrderViewModel> Orders { get; set; }        

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Orders = new ObservableCollection<OrderViewModel>
        {
            new OrderViewModel {OrderId = "Order1", InstrumentId = "Instrument1"},
            new OrderViewModel {OrderId = "Order2", InstrumentId = "Instrument2"},
            new OrderViewModel {OrderId = "Order2", InstrumentId = "Instrument3"}
        };
    }

    public OrderViewModel SelectedOrder
    {
        get { return selectedOrder; }
        set
        {
            selectedOrder = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

<Window x:Class="WpfTestProj.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTestProj"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOrder}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding OrderId}" />
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding InstrumentId}" />
                    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxOptions}"                                  
                              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedComboOption}"/>
                </StackPanel>                    
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```